# Weblogic with Hibernate getting javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, weblogic, jta

I migrating from JBoss to Weblogic 12C, all the project was working well on JBoss, but when trying to migrate to Weblogic i have this error.
So some context:

My database: **Oracle XE**
Application Server: **WebLogic 12C**

On the start script **startWebLogic.cmd** i added:

```
set PRE_CLASSPATH=%MW_HOME%\oracle_common\modules\javax.persistence_2.1.jar;%MW_HOME%\wlserver\modules\com.oracle.weblogic.jpa21support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar
```

On Weblogic console in Services -> Datasources i created a data source

Name: **OracleDS**

JNDI Name: **u_interface**

URL: **jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe**

Driver class: **oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource**

I can see on JNDI Names that u_interface is there.

I was able to test the connection to the database on Weblogic.

Now my application:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit
name="OracleDS"
transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>u_interface</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WeblogicJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <!--  property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/-->
            <!--property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" /-->
            <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
    </properties>
```

The EJB where i have the entity manager:

```
    @Stateful(mappedName="/ModuleDao")
  public class ModuleDao implements ModuleDaoRemote {

     @PersistenceContext(unitName = "OracleDS", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
     private EntityManager em;
```

The method getModuleByName that you can see on stack trace.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Module getModuleByName(String name) {
        List<Module> local = null;
        CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Module> cq = cb.createQuery(Module.class);
        Root<Module> root = cq.from(Module.class);

        Predicate cond1 = cb.equal(root.get(Module_.name), name);
        cq.where(cb.and(cond1));

        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        local = query.getResultList();
        if(local != null && !local.isEmpty()) {
            return local.get(0);        
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error on the line

```
local = query.getResultList();
```

The interface:

```
@Remote
public interface ModuleDaoRemote
```

So in another class i inject the EJB successfuly but when i call the method

> getModuleByName("Some string")

i get the error:

```
Apr 22, 2015 3:58:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
<22-Apr-2015 15:58:57 o'clock CEST> <Warning> <org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper> <BEA-000000> <SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null>
Apr 22, 2015 3:58:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: java.lang.NullPointerException
<22-Apr-2015 15:58:57 o'clock CEST> <Error> <org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper> <BEA-000000> <java.lang.NullPointerException>
Apr 22, 2015 3:58:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener end
INFO: Session Metrics {
    81423 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    7839815 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    7610 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
Apr 22, 2015 3:58:57 PM com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler createResponse
SEVERE: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is:
        javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is:
        javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:117)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:97)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy191.getModuleByName(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.ejb.module.Maestro.getModuleByName(Maestro.java:81)
        at com.example.webservice.ModuleLauncher.launch(ModuleLauncher.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:117)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:91)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:149)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:88)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1050)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:1019)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:877)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:419)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:868)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:199)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:640)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
        at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:108)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:284)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:293)
        at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:128)
        at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:844)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
        at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
        at com.example.ejb.dao.ModuleDao.getModuleByName(ModuleDao.java:77)
        at com.example.ejb.dao.ModuleDao_b09ccg_ModuleDaoRemoteImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:34)
        at com.example.ejb.dao.ModuleDao_b09ccg_ModuleDaoRemoteImpl.getModuleByName(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.ejb.dao.ModuleDao_b09ccg_ModuleDaoRemoteImpl_CBV.getModuleByName(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:84)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1885)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.wrapAndThrowResourceException(JDBCUtil.java:278)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:416)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:393)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.security.SimpleCallbackHandler.<init>(SimpleCallbackHandler.java:38)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getSubject(RmiDataSource.java:466)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:407)
        ... 82 more

<22-Apr-2015 15:58:57 o'clock CEST> <Error> <com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler> <BEA-000000> <EJB Exception: ; nested exception is:
        javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is:
        javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:117)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:97)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy191.getModuleByName(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.ejb.module.Maestro.getModuleByName(Maestro.java:81)
        at com.example.webservice.ModuleLauncher.launch(ModuleLauncher.java:52)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:67)
        at com.example.ejb.dao.ModuleDao.getModuleByName(ModuleDao.java:77)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.JDBCUtil.wrapAndThrowResourceException(JDBCUtil.java:278)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:416)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:393)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.security.SimpleCallbackHandler.<init>(SimpleCallbackHandler.java:38)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getSubject(RmiDataSource.java:466)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:407)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:393)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Need some help! 
Please feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: Which version of weblogic are you using? Older version of 12c does not support JPA2.1 Can you test your Datasource through web console?

Comment: Hello @AlexanderFedyukov, thanks for your help, i'm using 12C downloaded 3 days ago from Oracle's website, and i added the support for JPA2.1, as you can see on my post. I was able to test data source on web console with the result: Test of OracleDS on server myserver was successful. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. And what hibernate version do you use?

Comment: I'm using the latest version 4.3.9, which i added to the lib directory of my domain. %MW_HOME%\user_projects\domains\mydomain\lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, now its working.

Since Weblogic is closed source, and the NPE was on the application server code, i tried to change Hibernate Version, and i guess there are some conflict between Weblogic 12C and Hibernate latest version (4.3.9), because with Hibernate 4.1.1 its now working.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on WebLogic once upon a time, don't have anything to test with right now, but it doesn't seem like the JPA jta-data-source name is complete, doesn't it need to be java://u_interface?

Comment: Hello @Scott Sosna, thanks for your help, in fact i did try that but no, it seems that i'm using the right JNDI name.On Weblogic if i go to Servers->my server->JNDI Tree i can see that u_interface is on the top of the directory interface. Thanks

Comment: Yes, weblogic did not require java:/ prefix

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about equity of my solution, but have a lot of experience with weblogic.

You are using hibernate-entitymanager 3.6, which provide jpa 2.0. Try to upgrade hibernate-entitymanager to latest version or downgrade project to jpa 2.0

On my own opinion weblogic painfully applies to inner jar modification. If you are limited with application server choosing downgrade to jpa2.0 would be best solution.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, i was using JBoss on this project, but suddenly management changed to Weblogic. Everything was working perfectly on JBoss. When i posted this problem yesterday i was using the latest version of Hibernate (4.3.9) + Weblogic 12C + JPA2.1. Changing only the version: Hibernate (4.1.1) + Weblogic 12C + JPA2.1 its now working. Thanks

Comment: Hibernate 4.1.1 support jpa2.0. We are using 4.2.7 with weblogic, but can not upgrade to 4.3.x branch due to heavy jar hell.

Comment: Hy @Alexander, just to let you know that also works with Hibernate 4.2.7 and JPA2.1,

Comment: Yes, works, but 4.2.7 is not "jpa2.1ready" and then many abilities not available.